# "Render" unsigned integer values to texture without clamping to [0,1]

Tags: opengl, textures, frame-buffer

I am trying to render to an unsigned integer texture, with a blending function enable, so that in the end, the value in each texel will be the number of objects rendered on the texel.  So I assume I cannot use normalized integers.

For example, if I have a 2x2 texture, and I render `[ (0,0) (0,0) (0,1) (1,0) ]`, the texture result should be, `[ 2 1 ; 1 0 ]`.

I am trying to set up the frameBuffer, but the call to `glTexImage2D`, causes the `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT` when I use the formats I assume I need.

```
// this works
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 1024, 768, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

// this causes GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
             0, 
             GL_RGB32UI, 
             width, 
             height, 
             0, 
             GL_RGB_INTEGER, 
             GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 
             0 );
```

Is what I want to do even possible?  If so, which settings do I need to use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GL_RGB32UI <- Is this right?  Each texel value is 4 32bit integers?  The last time I did this and wrote a single 32bit integer to a texture, I used GL_R32I and GL_RED_INTEGER.

I've never had that error before but it seems reasonable if you're texture isn't big enough.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get additive blending working with an integer buffer, however I did get it working with a single channel 32 bit float.  I got the effect I was going for by outputting 1 / 2^30 in fragment the shader, with glBlendFunc( GL_ONE, GL_ONE ), then multiplying by 2^30 after reading back the pixels.